# How can javascript array included object be sended with Angular HttpClient?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a array like this.

```
myarr = [{ 'madde': '1' , 'deger': 'truea' } , { 'madde': '2', 'deger': 'falsea' }];
```

I want to send this array to my server

```
let dataitems = this.myarr.map( x => JSON.stringify(x));

const req = this.http.post( nestleapiurl + saveform , {
  'listitem': dataitems.toString() ,
}, {headers: headers} )
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Error occured');
      console.log( 'Gönderilen:' +  this.myarr.toString() );
    }
  );
```

i want to send in this format , but i couldnt do.

```
{
"listitem":[
    { "madde":"1" , "deger": "truea" } , { "madde": "2", "deger": "falsea" }
    ]
}
```

i can send the json below with postman app to the server, but i couldnt send it with angular js application.

[image: json format in postman]

how can i format my array to json ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
let obj = {};
obj["listitem"] = this.myarr;
obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log('obj', obj);
```

my example code below :

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

    obj: any = {};

    myarr = [{ 'madde': '1', 'deger': 'truea' }, { 'madde': '2', 'deger': 'falsea' }];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.obj["listitem"] = this.myarr;
        console.log('this.obj', JSON.stringify(this.obj));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `JSON.stringify` method.

```js
myarr = [{ 'madde': '1' , 'deger': 'truea' } , { 'madde': '2', 'deger': 'falsea' }];
let obj=JSON.stringify({'listitem':myarr});
console.log(obj);
```